# can't create instance of class from class name in a different namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create an instance of a class from its name.  It works if the class is in the same assembly.  But if the class is imported from another assembly, it fails even when I specify the full name of the class.

I created a class Class1, and put it in the class library MyClass.dll

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub sayHi()
        MessageBox.Show("Hi")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I created a 'Test' project that has a form, 'TestForm', with one button on it.  In the button's click method, I tried to create an instance of Class1

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports MyClass

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim className As String = "MyClass.Class1" 
    Dim classType As Type = Type.GetType(className) 
    Dim obj As Object= Activator.CreateInstance(classType)
  ...
```

the classType returned in line2 is always nothing, so line3 would fail.  However, if I put Class1 in the same 'Test' project, and do

```
Dim className as String = "Test.Class1"
```

Things worked just fine.  The 'Test' project can see the class "MyClass.Class1" (I verified it's the correct full name ), but can't get its type, why?  I'm using VS2008 on an XP machine.

Comment: have you added a reference to "MyClass" project in your "Test" project? Also what is the error message and exception type that you receive?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that will help you :

```
    Dim act As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("You outside class .dll Path")
    Dim Your_Class_is_here As New Object
    For Each ty In act.ExportedTypes
        If ty.Name = "Class1" Then
            Your_Class_is_here = act.CreateInstance(ty.FullName)
        End If
    Next
    Your_Class_is_here.sayHi()
```

i've test it in my own project and it's working *_^

**NOTE** : if you use this code no need to import or add reference that DLL to your Test Project.

Happy Coding ^^

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This requires that the client knows the full path of MyClass.dll as well.  I decided to get around the problem by including a helper class in MyClass.dll.  The helper class has a method to create an instance of any class in MyClass.dll by name and return it.  Thanks anyway.